# Updating Saved Record With Multiple Relationships, Most Efficient Method

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am developing an **android** app that allows users to create notes and save the notes in the android **sq lite database**.

- The notes can contain elements I call **UI** elements, and each UI element has a corresponding table in the database and is linked to the '`note`' table using the foreign key of the saved note.
- Whenever the user saves a note, I save the note with all its elements in their appropriate tables.The user may choose to continue editing after a save action is performed.

  Now, when the user tries to save again, I am presented with two options.

  1. Delete the note record and related records (UI elements) from the database and save the note again (`re-insert`). I consider this an easier method.
  2. Try and update the note table and tables related to the note, deleting UI elements that has been deleted and adding UI elements. I consider this as more tedious but logically correct.

I want to find out if there are any other methods that I can use to update an already saved record rather than these or if there is an improvement that can be made to these two models suggested.

Thanks.